# C++ newbie: Operation of make_shared

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, make-shared

I am new to C++. Can someone please let me know what is wrong with the following code segment -

```
class Person {
   public:
      const std::string& name;

      Person(const std::string& s): name(s) {}
      void dump(void) const {
         cout << name << endl;
         //cout << &name << endl;
      }

};


std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Person>> plist;

std::string namestr = "Hoo";
std::shared_ptr<Person> r1(std::make_shared<Person>("Dull"));
plist.insert({"Key1", r1});
auto u = plist.find("Key1");
shared_ptr<Person> v = u->second;
v->dump();
plist.erase(plist.find("Key1"));
```

My intention is to create a database of Person objects and I was trying to use shared_ptr for that.

v->dump() causes a segmentation fault. However, if I use the 'namestr' variable instead of the string literal "Dull" then the v->dump() appears to work correctly, i.e. the following -

```
std::shared_ptr<Person> r1(std::make_shared<Person>(namestr));
```

Also, the following way also seems to work even though I use a string literal in the intializer.

```
std::shared_ptr<Person> r1(new Person("Dull"));
```

Pointers to the mistake I am making would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry that should have read 'plist'. I'll correct the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Person {
   public:
      const std::string& name;

      Person(const std::string& s): name(s) {}
      void dump(void) const {
         cout << name << endl;
         //cout << &name << endl;
      }

};
```

this is storing a reference to a string whose life time is not guaranteed. You should do

```
class Person {
   public:
      const std::string name;

      Person(const std::string& s): name(s) {}
      void dump(void) const {
         cout << name << endl;
         //cout << &name << endl;
      }

};
```

You code fails because "Dull" created a temporary string that went out of scope immediately

Comment: Why did you remove the `const`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. That does make sense. What I was wondering was why does the following form *seem* work -  std::shared_ptr<Person> r1(new Person("Dull"));

Comment: because you have not tried to access anything that has disappeared yet. While that line is executing `std::string("Dull")` exists and you can create a reference to it. After the line executes "dull" disappears so the ref (`name`) is invalid. Things go bad when you try to use that reference

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `shamefaced` - cos i could not remember if the const rules for ref vs 'copy' were different and rather than try it I chickened out and dropped the `const` - since its not relevant to the OP problem